# Does this Rx code subscribe to the changes of the JSON itself?

Tags: ios, json, swift, rx-swift

I have successfully parsed `JSON` data using `URLSession`. The data is then passed to an `Rx` sequence and finally the data is bound to a `tableView`. Now, my question is, is the `JSON` data itself observed? I mean, if there are changes in the remote `JSON` data, will my `subscriber` trigger? I'm guessing no, and that you need to somehow wrap the `URLSession` in an observer as well. But how would I go about doing that? Anyway, here's the code:

```
func getJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/sbmzi") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

                let decodedJson = try jsonDecoder.decode(People.self, from: data)
                self.parsedJson.accept(decodedJson.people)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

And in `viewDidLoad`:

```
getJSON()

        self.parsedJson.subscribe(onNext: {
            print("Observing")
            print($0.description)
        }).disposed(by: disposer)

        self.parsedJson.bind(to: myTableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell")) { row, data, cell in
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(data.name), \(data.job), \(data.bestBook.title), \(data.bestBook.author.name)"
        }.disposed(by: disposer)
```

There's the `structs` for the parsed data as well, but no need to show them I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is the JSON data itself observed?**

A stored property `parsedJson` has a type `Observable` so, yes it's observable. You can modify the `parsedJson` stored property multiple times and resubscribe as well. You can do it for example when a user tap a button to refresh a datasource.

**If there are changes in the remote JSON data, will my subscriber trigger?**

No. To be informed about changes you have to trigger a `getJSON` method by your self in code or via timer or use a [web socket dataTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionwebsockettask) instead a Http protocol. Important: The web socket protocol must enabled on a server side before using a web socket data task.

Comment: Alright, nice, thanks for clarifying. I gues the end user could just scroll to the top, which will trigger the `getJSON` method, which will in turn give new data to the observer. Cool!